# Unsupported config option: 'healthcheck'

Tags: docker, configuration, docker-compose

I tried to add a healthcheck to my compose file but whenever I ran the compose file I get the following error.

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for balrogadmin: 'healthcheck'
Unsupported config option for balrogagent: 'healthcheck'
Unsupported config option for balrogpub: 'healthcheck'
Unsupported config option for balrogui: 'healthcheck'
```

My docker configurations are:

```
docker --version
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 3a232c8

docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

Comment: Can you paste in your `docker-compose` file contents?

Answer (score 12):

The `healthcheck` option was added in docker-compose file format 2.1. If you are using version 2 or version 1, it will not be available. The format version is typically on the first line of docker-compose.yml, as in

```yaml
version: '2.1'

version: '3'
```

Also, the healthcheck option requires Docker Engine 1.12.0 or later.

If you don't meet those requirements, it will not work.

Comment: I guess my Docker engine is up to date because after 1.12 they decuded to release versions of the format YY.MM instead of the regular convention. Most probably it has something to do with the compose file.

Answer (score -2):

delete the config option for balrogadmin: 'healthcheck',it will can work.